# Find linear Least Squares with Quadratic Constraint

Tags: optimization, least-squares

While using **Least Squares** algorithm, I'm trying to get $$f(a_1,a_2,v_1,v_2)=Aa_1+Ba_2+Cv_1+Dv_2-E$$ approximation under the constraint: $$v_1^2+v_2^2=s^2 (s\in\Bbb{R})$$

In the end, I got the following equation with the **Lagrange Multiplier**:
$$\left(M+
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&\lambda&0\\
0&0&0&\lambda\\
\end{pmatrix}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{pmatrix}=b$$
$$(M\in\Bbb{R}^{4\times4}, b\in\Bbb{R}^4) $$
And $M$ might not be invertible.

I am trying to get rid of $\lambda$ without any success...

I know that this question has been answered before, but I couldn't understand any of the answers there.

Can someone please send me an article or answer me in a more **simplified** way?